# How to convert one dimensional array of integers into map using streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have an array of integers and I want to convert it into a map.  I have tried using the code below.

But when I try using `Collectors.toMap()` using the below format, it is not allowing to map the array.

Code 1: It is working

```
int arr1[] = {-5, 15, 25, 71, 63};
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
IntStream.range(0, arr1.length).forEach(i -> hm.put(i, arr1[i]));
System.out.println(hm);
```

Code 2: It is NOT working

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm1=IntStream.range(0, arr1.length).collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i,i->arr1[i]));
```

Can anyone please explain how to convert the array to map using the `Collectors.toMap()` function?

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is that the `IntStream` is generating a stream of primitive ints.  Try boxing the stream before it hits the collector:

```
hm = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i->i,i->arr1[i]));
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : hm.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("(" + entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue() + ")");
}

(0, -5)
(1, 15)
(2, 25)
(3, 71)
(4, 63)
```

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You need to box the `IntStream` because it streams primitive integers and this causes compile error. Try with `boxed()` stream like this;

```
Map<Integer, Integer> result = IntStream.range(0, arr1.length).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> i, i -> arr1[i]));
```